# Modifying Google Search Plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I want Google search results to default with a publish date.  I'm trying to change the Google search plugin, but I'd be just as happy using a 3rd-party tool that does this.

So I'm using Firefox 15.0.1 and I've tried changing `{install dir}/searchplugins/google.xml`, but Firefox is just ignoring these changes.

For example, I'm adding the below in 3 places in `google.xml`, but nothing is happening:

```
<Param name="cdr" value="cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1900,cd_"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't read these files every time, it caches their content in the `search.json` file in [your Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile). The simplest way to make Firefox re-read your `google.xml` is to remove `search.json`, it will simply be created again with the new data on next Firefox start.

Answer (score 1):

May be the most simple way is to use the [Organize Search Engine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/organize-search-engines/) Firefox extension.

Select `Properties` to edit the search engine properties...

[image]